# Why does having Google Chrome installed make Firefox run slower?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, browser, malware

I have noticed that on Ubuntu 16.04, when I have Google Chrome installed, Firefox is much slower, crashes more often, and takes longer to boot up.

These symptoms (slowness, crashing, longer to boot up) vary based on the machine I am using, with one symptom per machine. For example, one machine may cause Firefox to be slower when Google Chrome is installed. On the other machine Firefox may crash more often. On the third machine, it may take longer to boot up.

These symptoms are not present when I am using Firefox before installing Google Chrome. Often I work on Firefox for as long as I can before needing to install Google Chrome to test a web app or two. However, after installing Google Chrome, one of the other symptoms always appears.

For example, on this current machine, Firefox shows a 'spinning wheel' for about ~40 minutes after boot-up. For these 40 minutes, the browser is unusable. However, if I open Google Chrome during these 40 minutes, both Chrome and Firefox begin working. If I close Google Chrome still during these first 40 minutes, Firefox stops working. After 40 minutes however, Firefox is working fine.

Edit: This is something I have noticed over the past ~2 years, and is definitely a thing. I am sorry that i don't have more concrete evidence. But it if it isn't something nefarious, then it probably has to do with a bug at the Chromium engine level.

Comment: Have the command `top` run in a tty and check what the resources are used for. I have NOT noticed this though and use chrome for browsing and firefox for online video (ie, netflix, ziggo tv and youtube),

Comment: You probably have a Chrome/Firefox extension problem. Temporarily disable ALL extensions in BOTH, and see if the problem goes away after a reboot.

Comment: I am slowly disabling chrome extensions to see what's causing it. It does seem to be something to do with javascript. Sites without javascript load almost immediately. Also any `npm` scripts I run take forever to run as well.

Comment: I have observed the same problem, both on ubuntu, and on windows, both 3 years ago, and now. Firefox isn't spinning for 40 mins for me, but startup time has definitely increased from 5 secs to about 60 secs.